# Как избежать потери данных при падении сервера?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Пишу небольшое приложение на Spring Boot'e, где происходят уведомления по времени.

Если сервер падает и его поднимают через некоторое время, все данные теряются.

Вопрос в том, как этого избежать (чтобы заявки на уведомление оставались), или как восстановить их? Желательно в виде кода какого-то примера.

Comment: Хранить не временные данные в базе данных

Comment: У меня есть подключение к БД, но они там не сохраняются ;   #database
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notification?true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

Comment: Почему они там не сохраняются?

Comment: ааа, там validate надо вместо create...